# parse POST request from HTTP Request body

Tags: php

What is the best and easiest way to get the HTTP Body from the POST request and parse it with variables? Say I have two attributes called latitude and longitude in the body in which the values I want to extract.

Another thing is how can I test it so I can see these values?

Comment: There's no such thing as a HTTP body

Comment: @SpliFF - not true.  An HTTP message has a header and a body.  See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html.  The header contains the user agent string, cookie values,etc.  The body contains the key-value pairs for the form post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP which handles the POST request you can do something like:

```
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
```

Some browsers have developer tools that allow you to see the POST data that the browser sent.  I use the FireBug plug-in for Firefox.  I think the built-in developer tools in IE 8 and above (F12 I think) can do the same thing.  Not sure about Chrome, but I'm sure there's something around.

Answer (score 2):

You're a little unclear in your question, if what you're asking is how to get the values of post variables, then PHP has the $_POST super global that you can reference as $_POST['key'].

If what you're asking is how to get some xml or something from the post body and parse it for values you might try the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA super global. It would depend how the data is formatted when it gets there.

Comment: +1 for mention of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, even though `$_POST` is probably what the OP wants :)

Comment: Yes I think $_POST does the job. However how can I test a POST using a browser? Is it even possible?

Comment: Easy, write a very brief HTML page that includes a <form> and an <input> and a submit type button.  Post it to your PHP script and see if the name from each of your inputs comes in as you expect.

Comment: See my answer for suggestions of browser-based testing

Answer (score 1):

read to $_POST like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
  print_r ( $_POST );
echo '</pre>'
```

and to access: `$_POST [variablename]` read more at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php